# How to find Geometric sequence ratio by sum, a1 and n

Tags: sequences-and-series

Lets say I know that I have a sum of $8.8$ and I know the first term's size is $1.3$ and I also know how many terms I have in the series, let's say $6$.

How could I find the ratio in which I have to multiple each following term until I'll reach $8.8$?

*For example* I got a series of $6$ terms ($6$ is a known):
$1.3$ (is a known)
$1.35,
1.45,
1.50,
1.55,
1.65$

Which all sums up to $8.8$ (known)
Not sure what the ratio factor is since I don't get accurate results.

In any case, I'd like to find out what r should be by knowing the three factors I know.

What formula should I use to calculate this?

Many Thanks in advance.

Roy.

Comment: Let the unknown ratio be $x$, then the progression is $1.3, 1.3 \cdot x, 1.3 \cdot x^2, \dots \,$. Write the condition for the sum of the first $6$ terms to be $8.8$ then solve the equation for $x$.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not so easy to compute explicitly. If your series has $n$ terms, then this comes down to solving a polynomial equation of degree $n - 1$. If $n \le 5$, then we have formulas for explicit solutions (though the formulas get progressively worse). For $n > 5$, we really only have numerical methods.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I've tried a few things but still didn't find a working formula..

Comment: @Ray There is no formula. The equation you get is a [quintic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function) which cannot be solved by radicals. The best you can do is a numeric solution.

Comment: Thanks for answer @dxiv, would you mind showing me how it could be done? 
Meanwhile I've managed to do this: Sn = [2a1+(n-1)*d]*n/2 which results in d=0.0666 which equals r= 1.0507 and this number gives me a growing deviation, especially after a few numbers in the series.. Isn't there a better/shorter/more precise way to do this calculation?

Comment: @Ray That looks like the formula for an arithmetic progression, so it doesn't apply here. The root you are looking for is [$\approx 1.04809$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E5%3D8.8%2F1.3) and there are many ways to approximate it numerically, see for example [Root-finding algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms).

Comment: Thanks for your help @dxiv